# StreamedResponse how to have control to the stream I get

Tags: json, flutter, http

I going to have API call which I able to map the data to the class while it is downloading and when I use StreamResponse, I will get the data chunks by chunks which it cut the in the middle of the array from the JSON. For example, the complete Json file is like below.

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "a": 4,
    "b": 5,
    "c": 6
  }
]
```

The stream may give me into few parts like

Part 1:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
```

Part 2:

```
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "a": 4,
    "b": 5,
    "c": 6
  }
]
```

Is there way to configure or control the stream I get, so that it will be complete array like this.

Part 1:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  },
```

Part 2:

```
{
    "a": 4,
    "b": 5,
    "c": 6
  }
]
```

I don't want to accumulate all the stream data, I want done it part by part, below are the example code I'm using right now.

```
final client = http.Client();
      final request  = http.Request("GET", Uri.parse(url));
      Future<http.StreamedResponse> response = client.send(request);

      response.asStream().listen((streamResponse){
        streamResponse.stream.listen((data) {
          String responseData = utf8.decode(data);
          print('Received $responseData');
        });
      });
```